# JRE System Library [WebSphere v6.1 JRE] (unbound)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following error in my build path: JRE System Library [WebSphere v6.1 JRE] (unbound) after importing a project into Eclipse. Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rightclick project, *Properties* > *Java Build Path* > *Libraries* > *JRE System Library* > *Edit*. There you can fix it by setting it to an existing (bound) JRE system library.

[image]

Select preferably the workspace default one so that the project is better portable across IDE environments (so that when this project is been exported and re-imported, the developer won't risk facing this particular problem once again).